# Edit/Update User Role Relationship using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

i am using user role relationship using hibernate that is available on so many websites.
But In my case user table already having users and roles table also having all the predefined roles. 
Now what i want is to fetch all the available roles from roles table and check box as "checked" if it is available to the given u`ser_id in third table(user_role).`

Comment: Can you post some code snippet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your Entity classes to use exist tables and columns names using name attribute in `@Table` and `@Column`, then the relation will be `@OneToMany` at user entity to the authorities entity with for ex `Set<Role>`, then in view you can make your check to know if this user have a specific role or not.